# Blockwise diagonal matrix inversion

Tags: matrices

I have a blockwise-diagonal matrix (not sure how to call it). It basically has square blocks of non-zero elements on the diagonal, and zeros everywhere else. The matrix takes the following form:

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
M_1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & M_2 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dots & M_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now I know that the inverse of a general two by two blockwise matrix can be expressed like so:

$$ 
Z = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
Z^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 
(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1} & -(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}BD^{-1} \\
-D^{-1}C(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1} & D^{-1}+D^{-1}C(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}BD^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If I replace B's and C's by 0, I get the following (to me logical) invert:

$$
Z^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
A^{-1} & 0 \\
0 & D^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My question is, does this stand for a blockwise matrix that has more than two by two blocks? Is the following true?

$$
M^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
M_1^{-1} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & M_2^{-1} & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dots & M_n^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Yes (if the blocks are square blocks, naturally), since you can multiply by blocks and obtain the block-diagonal matrix $\operatorname{Diag}(I_1, I_2, \dots, I_n)$.

Comment: Yes, I was currently heading in that direction :)

Comment: Great minds think together! ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out in the direction proposed by Bernard. Here's the development.

Given the matrix we are trying to invert, $M$, the product of this matrix by its invert should give an identity diagonal matrix, like so:

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & A_{22} & \dots & 0 \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & A_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
MM^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & I & \dots & 0 \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & I \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$.

If we assign block matrix variables to $M^{-1}$, we'll get a series of equation to solve:

$$
M^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
W_{11} & W_{12} & \dots & W_{1n} \\
W_{21} & W_{22} & \dots & W_{2n} \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
W_{n1} & W_{n2} & \dots & W_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

These equations essentially boil down to two forms, one items which will be on the diagonal of the resulting matrix (product of line=column=i):

$$
A_{1i}W_{i1} + A_{2i}W_{i2} + \dots + A_{ni}W_{in} = I \\
A_{ii}W_{ii} = I \\
W_{ii} = A_{ii}^{-1}
$$

Since all $A_{ij}$ where $i \neq j$ is zero, we get the second line of the previous equation. The other form is items which will be off the diagonal, or the product of line i with column j:

$$
A_{1i}W_{j1} + A_{2i}W_{j2} + \dots + A_{ni}W_{jn} = 0 \\
A_{ii}W_{ji} = 0 \\
W_{ji} = 0
$$

So we end up with the desired form.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider
$$ M = \pmatrix{ A & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & B & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & C} = \pmatrix{ \pmatrix{ A & 0 \\ 0 & B} & 0 \\ 0 & C}$$

Comment: Not false, but... does it bring something ?...